# How does a capacitor in an astable multivibrator turn off a BJT?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, astable

I've recently started learning about astable multivibrators. I understand that the capacitors in a circuit like the one below create the alternating current by charging up one at a time, and once they are charged up and the BJT next to them is closed, they get a negative potential which turns off the BJT on the other side by stopping current from reaching them. What I don't get, is how a capacitor getting a negative charge will stop current from the battery from going to the BJT all together. If, say, the transistor on the left is closed and C1 is charging, I feel that current from R2 should be able to split off at the junction to go left through C1 and right to the BJT on the right.
[image]

Comment: Those are npn BJT transistors, not MOSFETs.  If the base emitter junction gets above 0.7V, the transistor will turn on, discharging the other capacitor.

Comment: How can current from R2 go to left through C1 if left transistor is off? It all goes to base of right transistor.

Comment: A good (general) rule is: the caps always try charge to maximum voltage circuit topology allows. (Just a note..).

Comment: You might want to play around with [this simulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/691989/11683) that I set up as an answer to a related question.

Comment: "the transistor on the left is closed and C1 is charging" the left hand plate of C1 becomes more positive when the transistor on the left is not conducting. "Not conducting" is not the same as "closed".

Comment: Dave: A significant difference between this sch and your sim is that this one has LEDs in the collectors with no current path around them.  This changes drastically the discharge period for the capacitors.  6 V is probably not enough to push the LEDs into reverse conduction, so will the circuit even run?

Comment: These are just placeholder values, my question is more regarding the general operations behind an astable multivibrator.

Comment: BJTs and MOSFETs are *very* different. These are BJTs. This circuit will not work with MOSFETs as it relies on the base current of the BJTs.

Comment: (@AnalogKid: I have no idea what you are talking about. The LEDs have the *series* resistor the multivibrator needs. When would they need to conduct in reverse?)

Comment: See [Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?startCircuit=multivib-a.txt).

Answer (score 0):

When the left transistor turns on, the RHS of C1 will rapidly drop to a negative voltage below ground while its LHS is held at close to ground by the turned on transistor. C1 now charges through R2 and the voltage on the RHS of C1 slowly rises but the right transistor can't turn on until the voltage on the RHS of C1 rises to about 0.7 V above 0 V which is the approximate turn on voltage of the transistor. When the right transistor turns on it rapidly takes the LHS of C2 to a negative voltage relative to ground which switches off the left hand transistor and the process repeats.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitor gets charged or discharged if current flows through the capacitor. In this circuit: If the transistor on the left is not conducting, there is a current path from the positive supply through R1, the left LED, C1 and the base-emitter path of the right transistor. This path will charge C1 until the voltage of C1 reached a level that prevents further current from flowing through that path. In this circuit, the LED requires around 2V, the base-to-emitter path in the right capacitor requires around 0.7V, so if the capacitor accumulated enough charge to reach a level of 3.3V, the sum of the LED voltage, the capacitor voltage and the transistor voltage is 6V, which is equal to the supply voltage, so no further current will flow.

You should consider the voltage at a capacitor a secondary effect. The primary value to discuss at a capacitor is the amount of *charge* stored in it. Charge is created by current over time, and represents the number of electrons displaced in the capacitor. If you charged a capacitor of 10µF with an average current of 10µA for 3 seconds, you placed a charge of 30 µA*s = 30µC (C is the unit symbol for Coulomb, which is the same as Ampere multiplied by seconds) into it. The capacitor equation tells you that the voltage at the capacitor is 30µC / 10µF = 3V. While you can use the equation the other way to find out the charge of a capacitor if you know the voltage it has been charged to, you should keep in mind that physically, it's the charge that causes the voltage to appear and not the voltage that causes some charge to be in the capacitor.

When the capacitor is "fully charged", i.e. it reached 3.3V, the collector of the left transistor is at 3.3V (on the capacitor) + 0.7V (on the right transistor) = 4.0V. Now, if for some reason (to be explained later), the left transistor starts conducting, it will pull down the collector to around 0.2V, but this does not immediately change the amount of charge stored in C1, so the right end of C1 will still be 3.3V *lower* than the left end. If the left end is pulled to 0.2V, the right end is at -3.1V, which will turn off the right transistor.

Now, the primary current path through C1 changed: As the right end of C1 is below 0.7V, the base-to-emitter path in the right transistor does not conduct anymore, but some current can be sourced through R2. On the left side, the voltage is fixed by the left transistor being turned on. So now C1 is in the current path of R2 - C1 - left transistor. This current will discharge C1, and even slightly charge it in the "wrong" direction. As soon as C1 is charged to around -0.5V (measured from right to left, as we did all the time), the voltage at the base of the right transistor is enough to turn that transistor back on, which will then turn off the left transistor in the same way as we just discussed the turn-off process for the right transistor.